# How to set tab at position 1 in viewpager

Tags: android

I've two tabs. By default 0's position tab is selected but i wan to select tab at 1st position. I've tried by

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(someIndex);
tab.select();
```

also but it didn't work. I also search on stackoverflow and apply at position 1 but my app get crashed.

```
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Add Expense"));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Add Ledger"));

            final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager2);
            final TabAdapter adapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
  tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();

//        }
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener (new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
```

TabAdapter:

```
class TabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private int mNumOfTabs;

    TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                return new AddExpenseFragment();

            case 1:
                return new AddLedgerFragment();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

Comment: what will be pos?

Comment: in your case position 1. so viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

Comment: i've tried before by this viewPager.setCurrentItem(1); but app get crashed

Comment: No log cat error shown by this try {

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("sdf", e.getMessage());
        }

Comment: Check you AddLedgerFragment class

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code in my project and is working fine.But before this you have to set up your tab layout with View Pager

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
```

Comment: also app get crashed

Comment: problem is somewhere else than . post your crash logs